# Program log: panicked at 'range end index 36 out of range for slice of length 0', src/token/utils.rs:50:27

Tags: solana-program, web3.js

In file `metadata.js`:

```
const { config } = require("dotenv");
config();
const {
  Collection,
  CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts,
  CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionDataArgs,
  Creator,
  MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
  UpdateMetadataAccountV2InstructionAccounts,
  UpdateMetadataAccountV2InstructionData,
  Uses,
  createMetadataAccountV3,
  updateMetadataAccountV2,
  findMetadataPda,
} = require("@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata");
const web3 = require("@solana/web3.js");
const {
  PublicKey,
  createSignerFromKeypair,
  none,
  signerIdentity,
  some,
} = require("@metaplex-foundation/umi");
const { createUmi } = require('@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults');
const {
  fromWeb3JsKeypair,
  fromWeb3JsPublicKey,
} = require('@metaplex-foundation/umi-web3js-adapters');

// Function to load the wallet key
function loadWalletKey(privateKeyBytes) {
  return web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(privateKeyBytes));
}

// Define the initialization flag
const INITIALIZE = true;

// Define the metadata function
async function metadata(mintPublicKey) {
  try {
    console.log("Let's name some tokens in 2024!");

    // Replace with your metadata details
    const metadataDetails = {
      name: "GUDS Coin",
      symbol: "GUDS",
      uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CHToken/LoomDeployerBot/main/metadata.json",
    };

    // Ensure mintPublicKey is a string
    const mint = mintPublicKey;
    console.log("Mint Address:", mint);

    const privateKeyBytes = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.split(',').map(Number);

    const umi = createUmi("https://api.devnet.solana.com");
    const signer = createSignerFromKeypair(
      umi,
      fromWeb3JsKeypair(loadWalletKey(privateKeyBytes))
    );
    umi.use(signerIdentity(signer, true));

    const onChainData = {
      ...metadataDetails,
      sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
      creators: [
        {
          address: signer.publicKey.toString(),
          verified: null,
          share: 100
        }
      ],
      collection: none(),
      uses: none(),
      updateAuthority: signer.publicKey.toString(), // Add this line
    };

    if (INITIALIZE) {
      const accounts = {
        mint: mint,
        mintAuthority: signer,
      };
    
      const data = {
        isMutable: true,
        collectionDetails: null,
        data: onChainData,
      };
    
      console.log("Initialization Process - Step 1: Creating metadata account...");
      const txid = await createMetadataAccountV3(umi, { ...accounts, ...data }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
      console.log("Initialization Process - Step 1: Metadata account creation successful. Transaction ID:", txid);
      const signature = txid;
      console.log("Initialization Process - Step 2: Signature", signature);
    } else {
      const data = {
        data: some(onChainData),
        discriminator: 0,
        isMutable: some(true),
        newUpdateAuthority: none(),
        primarySaleHappened: none(),
      };
      const accounts = {
        metadata: findMetadataPda(umi, { mint: mint }), // Use mint directly
        updateAuthority: signer,
      };
      console.log("Updating metadata account...");
      const txid = await updateMetadataAccountV2(umi, { ...accounts, ...data }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
      console.log("Metadata account update successful. Transaction ID:", txid);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error:", error);
  }
}

// Export the metadata function
module.exports = { metadata };
```

Answer (score 3):

This error is being thrown from the mpl-utils program [here](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/23789d8983c7f87992c94a9502dc6294ec839f76/core/rust/utils/src/token/utils.rs#L50).

That line of code attempts to index `[0..36]` of the mint-account's data but finds that its data isn't up to that size. This implies that the mint-account is invalid. `CreateMetadataAccountV3` expects the mint-account passed to already be initialized.

Hence the fix is to first initialize the mint using the `InitializeMint` instruction. You can do that simply with:

```
import * as spl from '@solana/spl-token';

let mintAddress = await spl.createMint(
  connection, // the connection
  mintAuthority, // payer
  mintAuthority.publicKey, // mint-authority
  null, // freeze-authority
  0 // token decimals
);
console.log(`Mint account created with address: ${mintAddress.toBase58()}`);
```

Or by following the instructions specified in the solana [cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/token.html#how-to-create-a-new-token).

For a full specification of the `createMint` function and its arguments, see the source code [here](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/93b0969b678c92063e819a12558fcdd18f64c409/token/js/src/actions/createMint.ts#L7).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the mint is not initialized yet but you're trying to create the pda metadata account.
Use the "finalized" commitment when creating the mint like so:

````
  const mintPublicKey = await createMint(
    connection,
    keyPair,                    //Payer
    mintAuthorityPubKey,        //mintAuthority
    keyPair.publicKey,          //freezeAuthority
    decimals,
    keyPair,
    {
      commitment : "finalized"  //Finish initialazation of the mint first
    }
  );```
````

Answer (score -1):

your JSON metadata is the wrong format, its trying to parse some info that isn't there. please look at the Metaplex documentation for what to structure the JSON as and update the GitHub file.

Comment: thanks so much...