# Error creating mint and token account and minting tokens: SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, metadata, mpl-token-metadata

> In `main.js`:

```
const { config } = require("dotenv");
config();

const {
  Connection,
  Keypair,
  SystemProgram,
  Transaction,
  sendAndConfirmTransaction,
} = require("@solana/web3.js");
const {
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  MINT_SIZE,
  ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
  getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint,
  createInitializeMintInstruction,
  createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction,
  getAssociatedTokenAddress,
  createMintToInstruction,
} = require("@solana/spl-token");

// Import metadata function from metadata.js
const { metadata } = require("./meta");

let mint; // Declare mint variable here

// connection endpoint
const connection = new Connection("https://api.devnet.solana.com");

// Load private key from environment variable
const privateKeyBytes = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.split(",").map(Number);

// Wallet key pair
const walletKeyPair = Keypair.fromSecretKey(Uint8Array.from(privateKeyBytes));

// Function to create a token mint and associated token account and mint tokens
async function createMintAccountAndMintTokens() {
  try {
    console.log("Let's mint some tokens!");
    mint = Keypair.generate();
    const lamports = await getMinimumBalanceForRentExemptMint(connection);

    const associatedTokenAddress = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
      mint.publicKey,
      walletKeyPair.publicKey,
      false,
      TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
    );

    const transaction = new Transaction();
    // Add create mint instruction
    transaction.add(
      SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: walletKeyPair.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: mint.publicKey,
        space: MINT_SIZE,
        lamports,
        programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
      }),
      createInitializeMintInstruction(
        mint.publicKey,
        9, // decimals
        walletKeyPair.publicKey,
        walletKeyPair.publicKey,
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
      ),
      // Add create associated token account instruction
      createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
        walletKeyPair.publicKey,
        associatedTokenAddress,
        walletKeyPair.publicKey,
        mint.publicKey,
        TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        ASSOCIATED_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID
      ),
      // Add mint tokens instruction
      createMintToInstruction(
        mint.publicKey,
        associatedTokenAddress,
        walletKeyPair.publicKey,
        100000000000000 // Adjust this based on your token's decimal places
      )
    );

    const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      transaction,
      [walletKeyPair, mint],
      { commitment: "singleGossip", preflightCommitment: "singleGossip" }
    );

    console.log("Transaction Signature:", signature);
    console.log("Mint Public Key:", mint.publicKey.toBase58());
    console.log("Token Account Address:", associatedTokenAddress.toBase58());
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error during minting:", error);
    throw error;
  }

  // Call metadata function from metadata.js after minting
  await metadata(mint.publicKey.toBase58());
}

createMintAccountAndMintTokens()
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(
      "Error creating mint and token account and minting tokens:",
      error
    );
    throw error;
  });
```

> And in `meta.js`:

```
const { config } = require("dotenv");
config();
const {
  Collection,
  CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionAccounts,
  CreateMetadataAccountV3InstructionDataArgs,
  Creator,
  MPL_TOKEN_METADATA_PROGRAM_ID,
  UpdateMetadataAccountV2InstructionAccounts,
  UpdateMetadataAccountV2InstructionData,
  Uses,
  createMetadataAccountV3,
  updateMetadataAccountV2,
  findMetadataPda,
} = require("@metaplex-foundation/mpl-token-metadata");
const web3 = require("@solana/web3.js");
const {
  PublicKey,
  createSignerFromKeypair,
  none,
  signerIdentity,
  some,
} = require("@metaplex-foundation/umi");
const { createUmi } = require('@metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults');
const {
  fromWeb3JsKeypair,
  fromWeb3JsPublicKey,
} = require('@metaplex-foundation/umi-web3js-adapters');

function loadWalletKey(privateKeyBytes) {
  return web3.Keypair.fromSecretKey(new Uint8Array(privateKeyBytes));
}

const INITIALIZE = true;

// Modify the function to accept mint public key as an argument
async function metadata(mintPublicKey) {
  console.log("Let's name some tokens in 2024!");

  // Replace with your mint public key and metadata details
  // Now using the mint public key from main.js
  const metadataDetails = {
    name: "GUDS Coin",
    symbol: "GUDS",
    uri: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CHToken/LoomDeployerBot/main/metadata.json",
  };

  const mint = new web3.PublicKey(mintPublicKey);
  console.log("Mint Address", mint);
  const privateKeyBytes = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.split(',').map(Number);

  const umi = createUmi("https://api.devnet.solana.com");
  const signer = createSignerFromKeypair(
    umi,
    fromWeb3JsKeypair(loadWalletKey(privateKeyBytes))
  );
  umi.use(signerIdentity(signer, true));

  const onChainData = {
    ...metadataDetails,
    sellerFeeBasisPoints: 0,
    creators: none(),
    collection: none(),
    uses: none(),
  };

  if (INITIALIZE) {
    const accounts = {
      mint: mint,
      mintAuthority: signer,
    };
    const data = {
      isMutable: true,
      collectionDetails: null,
      data: onChainData,
    };
    const txid = await createMetadataAccountV3(umi, { ...accounts, ...data }).sendAndConfirm(umi);

    const signature = (txid);
    console.log("Signature", signature);
  } else {
    const data = {
      data: some(onChainData),
      discriminator: 0,
      isMutable: some(true),
      newUpdateAuthority: none(),
      primarySaleHappened: none(),
    };
    const accounts = {
      metadata: findMetadataPda(umi, { mint: (mint) }),
      updateAuthority: signer,
    };
    const txid = await updateMetadataAccountV2(umi, { ...accounts, ...data }).sendAndConfirm(umi);
    console.log(txid);
  }
}

// Export the metadata function to be used in main.js
module.exports = { metadata };
```

> The error as displayed on my terminal:

```
Let's mint some tokens!
Transaction Signature: 65idSm7yevAWNHneU9NFhLESGoGCRKeTNytea3rwn1rozuvznhuEgDm8DwewgEpnTCpXXkKfrZSP4PD7jiWAbYLU
Mint Public Key: Ai4D2eVv1gzFF1EtW8KDy2WxNshCHfDRFhopvFrgKkt3
Token Account Address: 23bEBK54K9xHEFVG4fXg9FicX5AKErEvpLMKohQxqSVU
Let's name some tokens in 2024!
Mint Address PublicKey [PublicKey(Ai4D2eVv1gzFF1EtW8KDy2WxNshCHfDRFhopvFrgKkt3)] {
  _bn: <BN: 903d9f42be35e670a25b6ebe4f6c185c18d4b6a40f21fc483ea2acea637da77c>     
}
Error creating mint and token account and minting tokens: SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete
    at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\TelegramBots\LoomDeployerBot\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:9560:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\TelegramBots\LoomDeployerBot\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:9526:20)        
    at async Object.sendTransaction (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\TelegramBots\LoomDeployerBot\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\umi-rpc-web3js\dist\cjs\createWeb3JsRpc.cjs:157:25)
    at async TransactionBuilder.sendAndConfirm (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\TelegramBots\LoomDeployerBot\node_modules\@metaplex-foundation\umi\dist\cjs\TransactionBuilder.cjs:213:23)
    at async metadata (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\TelegramBots\LoomDeployerBot\meta.js:77:18)
    at async createMintAccountAndMintTokens (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\TelegramBots\LoomDeployerBot\finalmains.js:103:3) {
  logs: [
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s invoke [1]',
    'Program log: IX: Create Metadata Accounts v3',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [2]',
    'Program 11111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    "Program log: panicked at 'range end index 36 out of range for slice of length 0', src/token/utils.rs:50:27",
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s consumed 11330 of 200000 compute units',
    'Program metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s failed: SBF program panicked'
  ]
}
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
```

Comment: Hello. I voted to close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/8641/program-log-panicked-at-range-end-index-36-out-of-range-for-slice-of-length-0). If you don't mind, check out the discussion there!


`Note`: A possible fix for your case might be to change the commitment argument in `sendAndConfirmTransaction` from `singleGossip` to `confirmed`, as that might be preventing your mint from being initialized.

Comment: Error creating mint and token account and minting tokens: SendTransactionError: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: Program failed to complete at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\TelegramBots\LoomDeployerBot\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:9560:13) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) at async Connection.sendRawTransaction (C:\Users\USER\Desktop\TelegramBots\LoomDeployerBot\node_modules\@solana\web3.js\lib\index.cjs.js:9526:20) at async Object.sendTransaction (C

Answer (score 0):

could you please share/ be more specific with the issue youre running into?

I can see the code and errors, but where are you seeing the error ? If youre working with metaplex SDK or their frontends trying to mint an NFT then i highly suggest looking at marc sacerberg (butchered the spelling sorry mark) open source forntend using UMI. Also from the logs i can see the use of Loom /telegram which makes it really hard for anyone to help you with the error.

Please trim down the code/error and try explainign what you are doing so we can provide specific help with some things pls

Comment: this is the error i faced when working with the code below